# Setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 2 (Pycharm)

Tags: python, pycharm, pythoninterpreter

System: ubuntu16.04 
Version of pycharm: Community 2017.3

When I create a new project,

[image]

I get the information as follows:

[image]

What is the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Try to removing all virtualenv* things in `/usr/local/lib/python/dist-packages/` and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I can create a project without getting disturbing information. I choose another interpreter.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ig9GW.png)